Ancient portable dishwasher hose is not compatible with ancient faucet
I was given a portable GE dishwasher (probably circa the last century)and the hose connection is not compatible with the equally ancient faucet. I rent and don’t want to switch out the faucet if I don’t have to, but besides its age the dishwasher has no issues and I want to use it. Are there adapters for really old faucets?

There are adapters.  You can add photos to your question for further help.

There are rubber adapters that don't require doing anything to the faucet, as long as the faucet neck is long enough.
